# iTextSharp - C# - Make a font bold as well as underlined

Tags: c#, fonts, itext

This is the code which I am trying to make a bold and underlined text.

```
Font header = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 15f, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
header.SetStyle(Font.UNDERLINE);
```

But all I get is underline and not bold. Is there any way I can get both underline and bold font ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As an alternative to using the `Font` to underline text, you can also use the `setUnderline()` method that is available for the `Chunk` class. When you use the solution explained in the answer by Joachim Isaksson, you can choose the line width of the line, nor the distance from the baseline of the text. The `setUnderline()` method gives you all that freedom.

Read my answer to the question [How to strike through text using iText?](http://itextpdf.com/question/how-strike-through-text-using-itext) for more info.

Take a look at these examples:

```
Chunk chunk1 = new Chunk("0123456789");
chunk1.SetUnderline(2, -3);
document.Add(new Phrase(chunk1));
Chunk chunk2 = new Chunk("0123456789");
chunk2.SetUnderline(2, 3);
document.Add(new Phrase(chunk2));
```

In both cases, the line that is drawn will be 2 user units thick instead of the default 1 user unit. In `chunk1` the line will be drawn 3 user units under the text (this is *underline* functionality). In `chunk2`, the line will be drawn above the baseline (this is *strikethrough* functionality).

Comment: What is "Chunk"? Which library is it referenced in?

Answer (score 16):

Try the following:

```
Font header = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 15f, Font.BOLD | Font.UNDERLINE, BaseColor.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 3):

I have used like this:

```
Dim font8Underline As Font = FontFactory.GetFont("ARIAL", 8, Font.BOLD)
font8Underline.SetStyle(Font.UNDERLINE)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please see 'Help' at the top right of the answer window to see how to format code.

Answer (score 3):

**Bold**

`Font1.SetStyle(1)`

**Italic**

`Font1.SetStyle(2)`

**Bold and Italic**

`Font1.SetStyle(3)`

**Underline**

`Font1.SetStyle(4)`

**Bold and Italic and Underline**

`Font1.SetStyle(7)`

1+2+4=7